# 3840x2160 resolution with Radeon HD 7870 not working

Tags: resolution, radeon

I just got a Seiki 4k monitor.

I am trying to get it to run at full resolution but so far no luck. It defaults to 1080i 60hz.

[This review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3R4Y6PPZ1QN29/ref=cm_cr_dp_title/188-8458477-2538744?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00BXF7I9M&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=172282&store=electronics) says it works by adding a mode with xrandr but he is using a different video card then me:

I am using a Radeon HD 7870 with the fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates on 13.04.

I followed the advice in the review and added a new mode with xrandr but when I try to change the output I get:

xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed

When I try to switch using amdcccle I get:

The current settings cannot be applied. Possible issues may include:
- Display(s) cannot be enabled.
- Setting(s) cannot be applied due to insufficient video memory.

The video card definitely supports 4k resolutions and I know it's possible to get it working on linux. I just can't figure out how to get it to work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seth - Just curious to find out whether the newer Catalyst drivers enable 10bpc (you can use [color depth test](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/display_settings.php) at source (7870) and if so, are you able to get 10bpc at 1080p, and possibly see 10bpc at full res (getting around the Seiki sink HDMI censorship) by using a mini-display port to HDMI adapter like Accel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed fglrx-updates and fglrx-amdcccle-updates and installed the latest catalyst driver downloaded from the AMD website. After that monitors correctly auto detected and set to correct resolution 3840x2160 30hz. Dual monitors also working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you output of xrandr -q shows that you want 3840x2160 resolution for DFP9

Run following command and add the newmode

```
gtf 3840x2160 59.90
```

Copy the line after Modeline and paste to "xrandr --newmode" i.e

```
xrandr --newmode "Output copied from above command"
xrandr --addmode DFP9 3840x2160_59.90
xrandr --output DFP9 --mode 3840x2160_59.90
```

Now when you run xrandr -q command you will get this resolution and * in this resolution which says it is selected.

To make it consistent make a script of this command and run it in startup 
OR 
make script inside /etc/X11/Xsessions.d .For this follow the [link](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2008/10/setting_up_dual_monitors_system-wide_with_xrandr_on_debian_lenny/)

Comment: Already did those steps but using values between 13 and 15 for refresh because anything higher then that causes error during --addmode. Switching to any of those newly added modes using --output causes error: "xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
"